# Is it possible to modify window object from a page that calls window.open('page1.html' ,'_self')?

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a page that calls window.open('page1.html' ,'_self'). Is it possible to do the modify the newly opened window object from the calling page. For example,

For example,

```
var myObj = {/*a large complex object */};
var w = window.open('page1.html' ,'_self')'
w.obj = myObj;
```

The above code does not work since it appears that the w.obj assignment never gets to execute.

Comment: You are assigning an object to some random property of the newly opened window, what did you expect to happen, execute what exactly? You can write content to the new window, execute functions both ways, and close the new window from the opener window, so yes you can modify a new window from the opener window, but you can't expect it to change just because you assign some random new property to it ?

Comment: I'm trying to pass data from the page (let's call it page0.html) to page1.html. The new page has to open in the same window. On page1.html, I want to be able to access the data stored by page0.html. For example, alert(obj.prop).

Comment: You can access data from the opener window by using `window.opener.obj` etc. in the new window.

Comment: Thanks. I tried window.opener.obj but it is undefined in page1.html. I believe it does not exist because page1.html has replaced page0.html via the _self param.